# Trigger @Scheduled method

Tags: java, spring

I use Spring's scheduler (`@EnableScheduling`) and have the following `@Scheduled` method, which is called every minute:

```
@Component 
public class ScheduledTask {

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 60*1000)
    public void run() {
    // ...
```

Now I would like to be able to trigger a scheduler run, on demand, from another place in the code.

I can inject `ScheduledTask` and just call the `run` method. However I want to make sure that there is only one thread running the `run` method at any given time. In other words, if the scheduler is currently running `run` I want the call to be ignored.

Also I want to call `run` asynchronously, but this can be easily addressed by using `@EnableAsync` and `@Async`.

Is there any Spring feature that can be used in this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edited as of comment:

Just use an AtomicBoolean.

```
@Component 
public class ScheduledTask {

private AtomicBoolean isRunning = new AtomicBoolean(false);

@Scheduled(fixedRate = 60*1000)
public void run() {
   if (isRunning.compareAndSet(false, true)) {

       // ... do your things

      //whenever you are done
      isRunning.set(false);
   }
```

I don't think there's something simpler in Spring. It makes no sense as it is really a flag thing.

Edit:

If you want to use it in several places of the application, consider implementing your own annotation with the semaphore or atomic boolean embedded.

Comment: This code is incorrect as it contains a race condition. What happens if two threads execute the run method at exactly the same time? Let's say thread1 executes the line with `if`, it is true, then thread2 executes the same line, it is also true. Since you have no synchronization it is possible that more than 1 thread will be running the `run` method. I have used the `Semaphore` class, but in this question I was asking if there is any Spring facility that can help here.

Comment: I think with AtomicBoolean you should be fine. No race conditions in there.